# How can I check if I can make outgoing calls?

Tags: android

Over whatever method the phone supports, i.e. GSM or CDMA (not SIP). I've tried using the ConnectivityManager, but the NetworkInfo for TYPE_MOBILE seems to return !IsConnected when connected to wifi, despite me having a full signal.

I want to know whether a phone call can be made, so I would guess TelephonyManager.getDataState is not appropriate.

## My Answer

(Can't post it for another 7 hours)

It seems I was in the right place, just not quite checking the right method. In fact, it seems that only one TYPE_ of connection (i.e. TYPE_MOBILE, TYPE_WIFI) will return IsConnected(), and so I should check whether the connection IsAvailable() instead. I tested this with mobile data both enabled and disabled, and it gave the correct result in both cases (that is: true when I have a mobile signal, false when I don't; both with and without mobile data enabled).

Note: To disable mobile data, in ICS goto Settings -> Wireless & Network -> More -> Mobile networks -> Data Enabled (unselect it).

Answer (score 0):

First check that PackageManager hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY) and then
you can use TelephonyManager getSimState()

Comment: SimState = {SIM_STATE_ABSENT, SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED, SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED,  SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED, SIM_STATE_READY, 
 SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN.

Comment: Sorry, I hate that pressing enter sends the comment and doesn't add a line. What I meant to say was that none of those will tell me if I have a mobile signal.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a BroadcastReceiver:
on case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK: check if the previous state was CALL_STATE_RINGING or CALL_STATE_IDLE (for example by settings a different flag in both cases).
In the latter case proceed with opening your application,:::

```
public class CallReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

                // Phone number 


                // Ringing state
                // This code will execute when the phone has an incoming call
        } else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)
                || intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                        TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {

            // This code will execute when the call is answered or disconnected
        }

    }
}
```

You should register you application to listen to these intents in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".CallReciever">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I wanted to know whether it was possible to make a call, not whether a call was in progress. There should be a simple way of getting this without having to monitor the state myself, and there is, see my answer.